# Trying to get the idea behind setRetrieveAllSinceLastBatch method in Exacttarget API

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am using **setRetrieveAllSinceLastBatch** method to retrieve all the records within a data extension who haven't been retrieved before. As per the method name it should do the job but I found some inconsistencies during my testing. I wanted to know how's that method is being implemented on Exacttarget side.

Here is one of my test scenarios :

1. I had a data extension initially with 4 records on Friday. I did a retrieve and got 4 records.
2. I added one more record through an api call on Saturday. Then I tried to retrieve the records and I got one which was ok because I set **setRetrieveAllSinceLastBatch** = true.
3. After few days lets say on Monday, I added  one more record through an api call. Then I tried to retrieve the records and I got 6 instead of 1. even though I had set **setRetrieveAllSinceLastBatch** = true.

So now I am confused about how this method functions?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: 1 & 2 are working as expected.  Not sure what's going on in #3.

Comment: exactly, do u know if anyone can answer that

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_all_records_since_last_batch/) are the docs on the actual functionality in C#.  I've never tried this on Data Extensions, typically only with tracking events. That may be where the issue is specifically.  I don't believe that function was intended for determining deltas.

Comment: Yeah, actually I only ended up using this method after going through that document. But the definition is not mentioned explicitly. So I dont know under what conditions I should use that method. thanks for your help though

Comment: I sent out a note to get clarification, but I have never used this outside of tracking events.  If they shed new light, I'll be sure to comment here.